# How to show balloon hints / notifications from tray in delphi

Tags: delphi, notifications, trayicon

I have a  thread in my program that checks if there is anything new every minute and if it is it should show a notification from tray like Balloon hint with notification text. Ex.: 'You got a new message from Tom!'

I use TTrayIcon component

Please help, thanks :)

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE3/en/TTrayIcon_%28Delphi%29

Answer (score 5):

To show a message in BaloonHint with TTrayIcon:

```
  TrayIcon1.Visible := True;
  TrayIcon1.BalloonHint := 'You got a new message from Tom!';
  TrayIcon1.ShowBalloonHint;
```